# max_recipients > 5 not working on Facebook apprequests (Invite Friends)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm making a invitation system to a project that I'm currently working on. The invitation system allow users to invite a limited number of their Facebook friends to use my project. Let's assume users may have only 20 invitations.

Facebook have a option called `max_recipients` that limit the number of invitations a user can do. This option is working fine for invitations <= 5, but this is not working for invitations > 5.

---

*In the end of the question you can find my code*.

**Here limiting invitations in 5:**
[image]

**Here limiting invitations in 20:**
[image]

**Following you can check my code:**

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId: "foobarfoobarfoobar",
    cookies: true,
    xfbml: true
  });
}

function FacebookInviteFriends() {
  FB.ui({
    'method': 'apprequests',
    'message': 'A hidden foobar description.',
    'max_recipients': '5', // if changed to '20', this stop working.
    'title': 'FooBar'

  // Callback (insert the invites in database)
  }, function(response) {

    // If user selected at least one user
    if (response.length != 0) {
      $.post('<%= invites_path %>', {
        request_id: response.request,
        to_ids: response.to
      }, function(data) {
        $('#remaining-invites').text(data);
      });
    }
  });
}

$('#invite').click(function(event) {
  fbAsyncInit(); // just for didatic purposes
  FacebookInviteFriends();
});
```

I'm following these two Facebook docs: [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.1#params) and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.Apprequest).

### Am I doing something wrong? How I can solve that?

Comment: Maybe you don't have more than 5 friends that Facebook think you should be able to invite

Comment: First, thanks for your reply. But I think you're wrong, I have more than 600 friends on Facebook and far I can see in the iFrame created by Facebook, I can invite all of them. Any other suggestion? :/

Comment: Could still be that Facebook think that the other 595 will not be interested so they only show 5

Comment: But Facebook iframe show all of my friends, WizKid. I just scroll down and it just don't stop to show me people that I can invite to my project :S

Comment: Does the `response` Object have a `length` property?

Comment: Yes (but if not, this makes no difference because it's working, the problem is with API call / Facebook iframe; the section with `response` is just the callback). Anyway, thanks for your reply :) Any other tip?

Comment: This bug is confirmed as a bug by Facebook Team, I will keep you updated and answer this question when the bug be fixed.

Comment: @Fernando Paladini Do you have new information about the bug? I got the same problem like you.

Comment: Of course. "We have managed to reproduce this issue and it appears to be a valid bug. We are assigning this to the appropriate team." Some days later: "Hi Fernando, our engineers are working to identify the problem. No ETA on a fix at the moment. Will keep you updated on this report."

Comment: Currently this bug was reported as private, I tell the Facebook Developer that are answering me to change the privacy of this bug to public, so people can follow the changes about this bug. If he change the bug privacy, I'll post the link here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a final answer from Facebook:

**"Hi Fernando, as it turns out the behavior to hide the counter for max_recipients > 5 was a deliberate product decision, so I am closing this as by design. I am unable to revert your report from confidential to public. Thanks for your patience."** (Dave Dosanjh, Facebook Team).

Because I cannot do anything about that and Facebook also don't will make anything about that, I'm answering and giving the best answer to this answer. There's nothing to do, guys :(.